# Laravel Blade Form Multiselect selected using array not working

Tags: arrays, forms, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get a multiselect in a form to work, I'm using laravel and I pass to my view a variable called **correlated**, an array of IDs, referring to the models related to select's model, here's the code where I make the confrontation :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

                @foreach($correlated as $c)
                @if($c === $brand_id)
                @php($selected = "selected")
                @endif
                @endforeach
                <option class="text-center" value="{{ $category->id }}" selected="{{ $selected }}">{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</option>
              @endforeach
```

I checked both brand_id and $c values, they're correct. Any ideas?

---

**edit :** corrected, seems the most correct, way, still not working...

```
@php $selected = "" @endphp
            <select multiple name="categoriesField[]" class="form-control" size="{{ count($categories) }}">
              @foreach($categories as $category)
              @php $selected = '' @endphp
              @if(in_array($category->id, $correlated))
              @php $selected = 'selected' @endphp
              @endif            
                <option class="text-center" value="{{ $category->id }}" @php echo $selected @endphp>{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>
```

**edit 2**: solved with code above, my browser somehow behaved wrong and didn't diplay the selected option, guess I'll check the only answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

Before your `<select>` tag store the brand ids in a variable

```
@php $brandIds = collect($correlated)->toArray() @endphp
```

Inside your `<select>` tag check if the value of your `$brand_id` variable is inside the `$brandIds` array using php `in_arrya()` function, then select that option as selected.

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
   <option class="text-center" value="{{ $category->id }}" @if(in_array($brand_id, $brandIds)) selected @endif>{{ ucfirst($category->name) }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: I need to confront $correlated (an array of IDs) and $category->id which is not an array (and containes the id to check to activate selected) so I can't use in_array

Comment: `in_array()` function takes first parameters a string and second array, so you can use it, first parameters as `$category->id` and seconds params as `$correlated ` which i stored in `$brandIds` , so you can use `$branchIds` as second params of in_array() function